# Туннель между виртуальными машинами Linux. Stunnel

Tags: linux, администрирование

Объясните, пожалуйста, как создать туннель между двумя виртуальными машинами Linux (Ububtu) с помощью Stunnel.
Основная цель: проверить различные сертификаты на российских гостах. Как они влияют на пропускную способность туннеля?  Проверять буду с помощью Iperf

Comment: Stunnel транспорт, какой пайлоад?

Comment: Пайлоада как такового нет. Просто с помощью Iperf нужно указывать какой размер данных будем передавать и смотреть что будет со скоростью передачи.

Comment: `stunnel` не для этого. Он — обёртка для программ, которые не умеют в SSL/TLS.

Comment: То есть я не смогу поднять туннель чисто на stunnel, шифровать с помощью, допустим, стрибога и передавать трафик для теста с помощью Iperf?